# Creating uninherited/unoverridable/nonvirtual methods in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm super stumped. I want to create a family of objects that all share common properties, but don't share methods. I would like

```
class X {
  x: any;
  myFunc() {
    console.log(this.x);
  }

  constructor() {
    this.x = true;
    this.myFunc();
  }
}

class Y extends X {
  y: any;
  myFunc() {
    console.log(this.y);
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.y = 2;
    this.myFunc();
  }
}

class Z extends Y {
  z: any;
  myFunc() {
    console.log(this.z);
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.z = "something stupid";
    this.myFunc();
  }
}

new Z(); 
// should print
// true
// 2 
// something stupid
new Y();
// should print
// true
// 2
new X();
// should print 
// true
```

The current behavior is for `new Z()` to print `something stupid` 3 times.

I would like a way to call a method inside a class that isn't overridden, but calls outside are. In C++, you can define a virtual public method and a private non-virtual method, and I would like to replicate something like that.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I don't know if this is an XY problem. I thought about it, but I really don't see how the context of the application I'm working on is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update in response to your comments and new question information:

It seems like you want a combination of [override (public) methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-3.html#override-and-the---noimplicitoverride-flag) and [private (method) fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_methods):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEAa0G8BQ1oA8Bc0wDsCeA3CtAMQBmOAFAJSLTAD2OEDIApgHQgMDmlALgAsAlhA5pqBaAF9iFGnSGiO5KpJlJijZvwBOAV2D8GuhclSolYtNAC80PfrZELDkWNU0XG2UlCQYAE1oNjR+NhwAExh4c2g8LFxCYk9aBHomFnYuXgF3Djx1WVQGADc2XV1hSLZoeTS3ZVSpX1RtCEcjEzNiVAh9AAcKr17GsTw7aAAmb0t85uJZX38oaAAtELCI6OhguIAvRPxvVLp21k5uPisOfaLiMoqqmrq1RXn6ls02zM7jUzSo36QwBszGt0mACIWABbNhKHA8aAdQbVSFgm4LVBLTTtfjQfaTHBsADu6y80AA9JSHAY2AAaaaM6EMOEIpEogZopD7DifKk0llskSI5H8VGRSG437xImk3YU6m0pyMqZIPB8tRSJVqvwymz2Ylk2CKmmONhINCa03Ki1AA)

```ts
class X {
  x: any;
  #fn() { console.log(this.x); }
  fn() { this.#fn(); }

  constructor() {
    this.x = true;
    this.#fn();
  }
}

class Y extends X {
  y: any;
  #fn() { console.log(this.y); }
  override fn() { this.#fn(); }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.y = 2;
    this.#fn();
  }
}

class Z extends Y {
  z: any;
  #fn() { console.log(this.z); }
  override fn() { this.#fn(); }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.z = "something stupid";
    this.#fn();
  }
}

const z = new Z(); // true, 2, "something stupid"
z.fn(); // "something stupid"

const y = new Y(); // true, 2
y.fn(); // 2

const x = new X(); // true
x.fn(); // true
```

---

Original answer:

You can do it by extending each of them from the same abstract class rather extending each from the previous. If you're extending each from the previous for the purpose of instantiation side-effects, then extension is probably not the optimal pattern, but I can't make another suggestion without a more concrete explanation of the problem:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgg3gKAQVEhngQFsBPAMQFcA7WBACgEoAuBANwHsBLACYBuPAF88eFGgwANBAFMAHhHn0BGbPkKLOwepREEKNBrDa4jhWD3pgeyeQDpkPAObMARIo+sRhcUbWttC08DxQ5lqECGC0AA7yEb6WCBAAFnxgjooIALypULTyftHpmY5UdIxsJeIBUugIAJoKyqrqWBaElLr6hoSVppEpQXYOzm6elD61ElY2JKEQ4cPRMfGJNSllWZR5CABMJYQ7FSbVyf5iEg0YAFqtKmoaXQgAXr0Gc8ZVZqyv81s9icLncHjeMyMAUBizCSQB6wSSWOqQyWTe+w8dnI8jK9FcMQg8UEHhRp0GF1mAXo8gA7gg7lsgA)

```ts
abstract class C {
  abstract myFunc (): void;
}

class X extends C {
  x: any;

  myFunc() {
    console.log("x");
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.x = true;
    this.myFunc();
  }
}

class Y extends C {
  y: any;

  myFunc() {
    console.log("y");
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.y = 2;
    this.myFunc();
  }
}

class Z extends C {
  z: any;

  myFunc() {
    console.log("z");
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.z = "something stupid";
    this.myFunc();
  }
}

new Z(); // logs "z"
```

---

Note that, other than the nominal inheritance of the abstract class, this pattern is no different than `implement`ing from an interface:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMLIN4ChnILYCeAYgK4gLIAUAlAFzIBuA9sACYDcWAvllggDZwAzkOQANZMDwAHfhDwRwo9NlwAPenBAFOOfMTIIamPbgRMQQpnIB0-JgHNKAIjXPqnXDz3nLYKCQIYExQxqq4yGAAFsBCNmrIALyRARCeEdGxNoSk5DTpPN4CwqIAmpIycgpKaCa4BJraurg5hmGmyL5WtvZOzgTuBbxmFkL+gcGh1HUZMXEEScgATOm4mXGteR56hbzFIsgAWhWy8opgyjMAXo06w-q5RtPhI5bWEHaOLleDO-dd4yCIXaEUicxsV0WzisCkyIAcyDGJGkbGcqzBWU2TyG3hAEAA7kd8lggA)

```ts
interface C {
  myFunc (): void;
}

class X implements C {
  x: any;

  myFunc() {
    console.log("x");
  }

  constructor() {
    this.x = true;
    this.myFunc();
  }
}

class Y implements C {
  y: any;

  myFunc() {
    console.log("y");
  }

  constructor() {
    this.y = 2;
    this.myFunc();
  }
}

class Z implements C {
  z: any;

  myFunc() {
    console.log("z");
  }

  constructor() {
    this.z = "something stupid";
    this.myFunc();
  }
}

new Z(); // logs "z"
```

Comment: This doesn't preserve the hierarchy I was looking for; I want Z instances to have access to `x` and `y` and I'd like them to be constructed in the same way that they are in X and Y without code duplication.

Comment: @user3210986 That requirement isn't quite well-defined enough for me to respond. Can you write a series of tests as a set of definitive criteria (in JavaScript is fine), and then edit your question with them? Otherwise we're just guessing at what it is that you are after because your descriptions so far have been non-literal in terms of code behavior.

Comment: Sure. I have one in the code already, but I'll add some more.

Comment: I added more clear functionality requirements, thanks.

Comment: @user3210986 See my updated answer.